# NHANES Weighting

Tags: spss, weighted-data

I am in the process of analyzing some data derived from 8 cycles of NHANES data. Due to the nature of my research, my sample size is rather small (n=98). Since NHANES surveys utilize a complex sampling approach, I have weighed the data accordingly (and correctly if I am not mistaken!).

In leu of this process, I have two questions:

1. Should a participant's weight impact all variables involved in my research? For instance, if an individual is weighted as "394.57", will a continuous variable with a value normally "45" now be 45(394.57) = 17755.65? I am asking because the significance of my statistical work (independent samples t-test) changes markedly when I compare the outcomes between my weighted and unweighted data.
2. Given these results, one of my mentors suggested that I should not apply sample weights and analyze the data as is; they state that they knew of students who had used NHANES data in the past decided ultimately not to consider sample weights as part of their analysis. Is this something that is often done, or something that I should consider?

I am really pleased with my results so far, but I wanted to make sure that my understanding of weighted values was correct while seeing if I needed to use weights to begin with. Any advice on this topic would be greatly appreciated!

***Conducting this analysis in SPSS!

Answer (score 1):

That's not what weighting does. Weighting doesn't apply to *variables* in the data; it applies to sums in the computation.

For example, if you're estimating a mean, the unweighted formula is

$$\bar X = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}=  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n1}$$
and the unweighted formula is
$$\bar X = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}=  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n w_iX_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}$$

If you're doing regression, the unweighted formula for $\hat\beta$ is the solution of
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(y_i-x_i\beta)=0$$
and the weighted formula is the solution of
$$\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i(y_i-x_i\beta)=0$$
and so on.

Custom and practice differs in different fields as to whether all analyses should be weighted.  I would argue that they all should be weighted if any of them are weighted.

Part of the reluctance to do weighted analysis has classically been that software isn't available -- SPSS, for example, will not give the correct standard errors for a design-weighted analysis unless you buy the Complex Samples module.

(Base SPSS also won't give the correct standard errors for an unweighted analysis of NHANES, since NHANES has a small number of large clusters, a feature that inflates the variance relative to a sample of the same number of people taken independently as individuals. A two-year wave of NHANES has about 7500 people but only 15 clusters.)